# Invalid Credentials for WebApp only from the hosting IIS Server

Tags: authentication, iis, iis-8

When I try to access any of our Windows Authentication webapps that is hosted on our IIS box, I always get a 401.1 error. This only happens if I try to access it while logged into the IIS box itself. If I access the page the "normal" way of going to the url from a different computer, it's fine (asks for credentials and then authenticates ok). Only if I am logged into the IIS server will it fail to authenticate.

I found this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/871179/you-receive-an-http-error-401-1---unauthorized-access-is-denied-due-to from Microsoft, however it's not helping. I tried to follow the multiple application pools workaround, however I don't have a `c:\Inetpub\Adminscripts` folder. I searched the server for `adsutil.vbs` file and found it in `C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-iis-legacyscripts_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.16384_none_6f04ccf44b2e0531`. When I tried to run it, I got invalid character. Opening the file shows nothing but gibberish as if it's been corrupted.

This is a Windows Server 2012 with IIS version 6.2 (Build 9200) fyi. We are in a domain environment and I'm using a domain account to run the apps (not the default application pool).

I should also add that this happens when another app tries to reference a url that is hosted on the same server as itself. i.e. one app tries to use a web api that resides on the same IIS box as itself. This returns a 401.1.

Comment: You are using IIS 8 (learn what are the IIS releases via Google please). And you probably hit the famous loopback issue, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/896861/you-receive-error-401-1-when-you-browse-a-web-site-that-uses-integrate, not the one you told.

Comment: Why in the world would Microsoft call it 8 if the version number is 6????? How is anyone supposed to know that? Tag updated per @Lex Li's assertion of what version of IIS I'm using.

Comment: 6.2 is the Windows version number. Both Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012 use that number. You would have to get used to such, as different Microsoft product teams use different counting methods.